# On Mondays getting Friday's Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below script on Mondays goes 3 days back other days goes 1 day back.
I think it does not work properly. 
Can you help me to fix it?

```
MyDate>=dateadd(dd,case substring(datename(dw,getdate()),1,3)
when 'MON' then -3 else -1 end,getdate())
```

Comment: What does it mean "I think it does not work properly" ? What results or errors are you getting?

Comment: It doesn't capture all data which resulted on Friday. Some data is missing!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that might be because you're using `GETDATE()` as the 3rd parameter to `DATEADD`, which has the time part as well.

That will take you 3 days behind (actually 3 * 24 hours behind), but it will not capture the start of Friday or anything happening before 3 * 24 hours ago.

Say you're running the query on Monday at 11:45 AM, that will get you all of the data from Friday starting 11:45 AM, but nothing before that, which is because of the "time" part of the data.

Below is a modified version of your code which will capture all of the data/rows that happened on Friday (all day).

```
MyDate>= dateadd(dd, case 
                        substring(datename(dw,getdate()),1,3)
                            when 'MON'
                                then -3 
                            else -1 end
                        ,cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

To solve this, just do a quick hack and convert `getdate()` to date and the to datetime to generate a date/time combination that contains the start of the day.

Here's a quick example of what it does:

```
select
    getdate()
    , cast(getdate() as date)
    , cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)

2016-08-24 13:05:11.603 | 2016-08-24 | 2016-08-24 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm curious what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I ticked it by mistake. I just marked it the right answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user6751695 Well, please untick the downvote if you didn't mean to :)

Answer (score 1):

```
MyDate>=case 
when datename(dw,getdate())='Monday' 
then dateadd(day,-3,cast(getdate() as date)) 
else dateadd(day,-1,cast(getdate() as date)) end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use below query.

```
select case when datepart(weekday ,cast((floor(cast(getdate() as float))) as datetime)) = 2
            then (select cast((floor(cast(getdate() as float))-3) as datetime))
            else (select cast((floor(cast(getdate() as float))-1) as datetime))
           end as Date
```